# How to open a encrypted Url in python?

Tags: python, url, encryption, python-webbrowser, man-in-the-middle

I consider my URL as a string and encrypt it, the problem is that after i encrypt it, so that it is safe from any man in the middle attack, i want to open the url using a python function to open that encrypted Url, but all commands in python to open the Url requires the url to be in plain string format.

what can be done?

kindly suggest

Comment: The URL string is encrypted?

Comment: do you want to open the url without decrypting it!

Comment: The concept if encryption is that encrypted data is not useful until it is decrypted.

Comment: If you want to prevent MitM attacks, deploy TLS (i.e. HTTPS).

Comment: Step 1: decrypt the URL to a string.  Step 2: use the decrypted URL to open the website.

Comment: Yes, the aim is to open the URL without de-crypting it, since while i use kali linux for my MITM  attack i am unable to see my link.

Comment: the mitm attack in kali linux would be able to see the decrypted url which, i want to protect